# How to Remove Outlet New Work Box attached to Stud Bracket?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, studs, brackets

My wife and I found this problem where we want to replace a new work box? with an old work box that will allow for a new outlet to be place in there, however the old box is attached to this metal bracket which is nailed into a stud. I was wondering how would we go about removing this?

[image: Frontal of Outlet Box Wanting replacement]

[image: Side view of outlet box]

Answer (score 2):

Get a crowbar or pry bar and pound it underneath the nails and pull them out. If you have a rotary tool with a cutoff wheel, you can cut off the nail heads and avoid all the pounding. An angle grinder will also do the job. I'd replace it with a new work box since the stud is exposed. The new work box will be stronger.

Comment: Agree and will add that an oscillating tool (“Fein” for us oldtimers) would also do well for this.